# Дождаться завершения потоков

Tags: c++, многопоточность, pthread

В цикле запускаю n потоков

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   thread th(func);
```

Как затем их всех дождаться при помощи join()? Как в  POSIX потоках:

```
pthread_t tid[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   pthread_create(&tid[i], 0, func, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   pthread_join(tid[i], 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну что-то типа

```
vector<thread> th;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    th.emplace_back(thread(func));
for(auto& t: th) t.join();
```